# Show button if input text field is not empty in Wicket

Tags: java, wicket

There is input text field and submit button. I would like to show button text field not empty and otherwise button should be not visible.

```java
            TextArea<String> textMessageField = new TextArea<>("textMessage", textMessageModel);
            Button submitBtn = new Button("saveReminderButton") {
                @Override
                protected void onConfigure() {
                    super.onConfigure();
                    String text = textMessageField.getModelObject();
                    setVisible(text != null && !text.isEmpty());
                }
            };

            textMessageField.add(new OnChangeAjaxBehavior() {
                @Override
                protected void onUpdate(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
                    target.add(submitBtn);
                }
            });
            submitBtn.setOutputMarkupId(true);
```

I'm trying to use `setVisible` method in `onConfigure` but it doesnt work. I tried to use instead `setEnabled` and it was working but I need the same functionality with hide/show button

Comment: I always override isVisble for this purpose

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you make the button invisible you need to use  `submitBtn.setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true);` instead of  `submitBtn.setOutputMarkupId(true);`

This is important because without `setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true)` Wicket Wicket will render nothing for this component. With `setOutputMarkupPlaceholderTag(true)` it will render `<htmlElement id="someId"></htmlElement>`. This way Wicket Ajax could find it in the DOM and replace it with the HTML of the visible one.